# C# - Dynamic linq from a condition list

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have two classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ProductNumber { get; set; }

    public string ProductColor { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance:

```
Customer[] c = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName1",
        LastName = "LastName1",
        Product = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ProductColor = "ProductColor1",
                ProductNumber = "11"
            }
        }
    },
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName2",
        LastName = "LastName2",
        Product = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product()
            {
                ProductColor = "ProductColor2",
                ProductNumber = "12"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I use `System.Dynamic.Linq` library to filter my array:

`var filter = c.Where("FirstName == \"FirstName1\"").Select(x => x).ToList();`

I create a class `condition` and one instance:

```
public class condition
{
    public string propertyName { get; set; }

    public string  propertyValue { get; set; }
}

List<condition> f = new List<condition>
{
   new condition()
   {
       propertyName = "FirstName",
       propertyValue = "FirstName1"
   },
   new condition()
   {
       propertyName = "Product.ProductColor",
       propertyValue = "11"
   }
};
```

I want to create multiple clause `Where` from this `List<Condition>`

How to do this ?

Comment: Can you show the code where you currently apply one condition to the list? It should be as simple as `var toFilter = sourceCollection.AsEnumerable(); foreach (var condition in conditions) { toFilter = toFilter.Where(condition); }`.

Comment: Are your all proeprties typeof string?

Comment: No, all properties is not type string

Comment: I have a exception for : `c.Where("Product.ProductColor == \"13\"")` `No property or field 'ProductColor' exists in type 'List`1'`. How to use `Where` clause on sub property or on sub list property?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather it's just a simple case of performing this on your list? Unless I am missing something?

```
 var query = f.Where(x => x.propertyName == "FirstName" && x.propertyValue == "FirstName1");
```

Comment: My condition list comes from a configuration file

Comment: This may help you, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library there is a downloadable dynamic linq library with samples also here - http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx

Comment: Well with the samples provided by the link you can create string to represent your where statement for example - f.Where("propertyName = @0 and propertyValue = @1", "SomeNameHere", "SomeOtherValue");  So you can build up a string dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem I have modified a little bit your condition class as follwoing:

A condition for a customer might contains a list of product conditions:

```
public class Condition
    {
        public string propertyName { get; set; }
        public string propertyValue { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    }
```

To create it:

```
  List<Condition> f = new List<Condition>
  {
    new Condition()
    {
      propertyName = "FirstName",
      propertyValue = "FirstName1",
      Conditions = new List<Condition>
      {
        new Condition
        {
          propertyName = "ProductColor",
          propertyValue = "11"
        }
      }
    },
  };
```

now you can use the query below to filter the customer and the products with the given condition/s:

```
  var filteredCustomers =
              from condition in f
              from custmer in c
              from product in custmer.Product
              let propertyName = condition.propertyName
              let propertyValue = condition.propertyValue
              where (nameof(custmer.FirstName) == propertyName && custmer.FirstName == propertyValue)
                    &&
                    (condition.Conditions.Any(p => p.propertyName == nameof(product.ProductColor))
                    && condition.Conditions.Any(p => p.propertyValue == product.ProductNumber))
              select custmer;

            foreach (var filterCustmer in filteredCustomers.Distinct())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(filterCustmer.FirstName);
            }
```

Comment: u can give the property name as string instated of nameof and the problem is your customer class. This class contains a list of products that means you need to map them with an ideintfier but in you class there is nothing u can map with it.